# What are they singing on the Hot Top Volcano soundtrack?

Tags: game-music-identification, diddy-kong-racing

Does anyone know what they are singing in the song for Hot Top Volcano? [Here is the soundtrack on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hot+top+volcano+diddy+kong+racing).

Comment: I'm getting this error message when attempting to view the linked video: "*Video unavailable - This video contains content from Nintendo, who has blocked it on copyright grounds.*" Anyone know of a video or audio link that can be used to replace the one in the question?

Comment: @galacticninja: I have changed the link

Answer (score 2):

It's probably an Hindi song, it should be something like this:

> Garmane hula mungna
>   Garmane hula muckna
>   Hula mungna, hula muckna
>   Hula mungna, mungna, mungna

But I don't know if it actually makes any sense.

Comment: Knowing that this came just after the 'Muslim prayer in the fire temple song' of OoT, I would guess music was checked closely for any other Nintendo centric N64 game. So I would put forward the guess that it sounds like, but is jumbled so it doesn't mean anything in any language.